# Can't find the problem with my recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i new in Recycle view , i'm stuck when i display the text but already call from my database. i'h a lot research and can't find anything where the problem. i dont know i display the text true or false.

somebody can help me and checking my code.

MonitorCatalog.class

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monitor_catalog, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    list = new ArrayList<CatalogDatabase>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Catalog").child("Monitor").child("Basic");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                CatalogDatabase cd = dataSnapshot.getValue(CatalogDatabase.class);
                list.add(cd);
            }
            adapter = new RecycleAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Opss.. Something is wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

RecycleAdapter.class

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<CatalogDatabase> catalogDatabases;

public RecycleAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<CatalogDatabase> cd)
{
    context = c;
    catalogDatabases = cd;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.nameItem.setText(catalogDatabases.get(position).getNameItem());
    holder.priceItem.setText(catalogDatabases.get(position).getPriceItem());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return catalogDatabases.size();
}

class  MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    TextView nameItem, priceItem;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nameItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.basicname);
        priceItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.basicprice);

    }
}
}
```

I hope anyone can help my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating on each data change a new adapter and apply it to your `RecyclerView`. This forces your list to reload from 0 each time a new data change comes in. Instead, update your list object and notify your adapter that data has changed.

In other words:

1. Remove the following lines from `onDataChange`

```java
adapter = new RecycleAdapter(getActivity(), list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2. Add them below your list initialization:

```java
// ...
list = new ArrayList<CatalogDatabase>();
adapter = new RecycleAdapter(getActivity(), list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
// ...
```

3. Tell the adapter on data change that the data set changed:

```java
// ...
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        CatalogDatabase cd = dataSnapshot.getValue(CatalogDatabase.class);
        list.add(cd);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
// ...
```

You can also use `adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size()-1)` instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` if the item was added to the end of the list (and no other changes happened meanwhile). This will improve your app performance a bit.

See also the other `adapter.notify-` methods that might be helpful.